# SCCM PXE Boot failed. No advertisements found

Tags: pxe-boot, sccm-2012-r2

I'm encountering an issue with SCCM PXE deployment for unknown devices.
Here is my current setup:

10.0.0.10/24 - AD, DHCP

10.0.0.15/24 - SCCM 2012 (app catalog webservice point, app catalog website, component server, fallback status point, management point, site server, site system)

10.0.0.16/24 - MSSQL 2012 (site database, component, site system)

10.0.0.17/24 - Distribution Point (Component, distribution point, site system, software update point)

The distribution point is PXE enabled and as of now WDS seems to be configured by SCCM.
When i boot a client in PXE mode and check the SMS_DP$\sms\logs\smspxe.log i get:

```
<![LOG[Getting boot action for unknown machine: item key: 2046820353]LOG]!><time="08:16:35.560-60" date="02-18-2016" component="SMSPXE" context="" type="1" thread="3496" file="pxehandler.cpp:235">

<![LOG[Client boot action reply: <ClientIDReply><Identification Unknown="0" ItemKey="2046820353" ServerName=""><Machine><ClientID/><NetbiosName/></Machine></Identification><PXEBootAction LastPXEAdvertisementID="" LastPXEAdvertisementTime="" OfferID="" OfferIDTime="" PkgID="" PackageVersion="" PackagePath="" BootImageID="" Mandatory=""/></ClientIDReply>]LOG]!>

<time="08:16:35.638-60" date="02-18-2016" component="SMSPXE" context="" type="1" thread="3496" file="libsmsmessaging.cpp:6718">

<![LOG[00:15:5D:02:85:20, BF92CB0C-508A-4EA5-B798-BE7C5BAB3857: no advertisements found]LOG]!><time="08:16:35.638-60" date="02-18-2016" component="SMSPXE" context="" type="1" thread="3496" file="database.cpp:518">
```

My tasksequence is a custom tasksequence that should only boot up the WinPE image.

I'm using SCCM's boot images for x64. My workflow to deploy everything was:

1. Create task sequence
2. Deploy task sequence to unknown devices group
3. Update boot images to distribution point

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Markus

Answer (score 2):

The solution was rather simple still not documented anywhere!

You have to set the the availability time of the deployment to 12 hours in the past and it will work.

Thanks Microsoft Moderator guy Jason!

Comment: Yup.  I think it's some sort of time zone bug.  FWIW if you have more than one task sequence and only one is brand new, it will boot to WinPE but the new one will be missing from the selection list unless you set the new task sequences' deployment time in the past.

Comment: Add a synonyms, error message: "configuration manager is looking for policy“.  It works for me!! Thank you.

Comment: Signed up just to reply to this. I had to use this trick to fix the same issue in MECM 2303. I assume it's not a bug, but a feature. :) Thank you 7 years later!